# python can't recognize 3D array

Tags: python, matplotlib

i would like to create  a custom function, which takes machine learning model and coresspondng X and y  arrays and will plot 3D  decision function for  support vector machines, but when  i  run the code it gives me following error :
 `ax.plot3D(X[y == 0, 0], X[y == 0, 1], X[y == 0, 2], 'ob') IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed`

but issue is , that  i have created array  with 3  column, here is corresponding example :
`X, y= make_classification(n_samples=4000,n_features=3,n_informative=3,n_redundant=0,random_state=1)`

here is full code :

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
def plot_3D_surface(mode,X,y):
    model.fit(X, y)
    z = lambda x, y: (-model.intercept_[0] - model.coef_[0][0] * x - model.coef_[0][1] * y) / model.coef_[0][2]

    tmp = np.linspace(-5, 5, 30)
    x, y = np.meshgrid(tmp, tmp)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.plot3D(X[y == 0, 0], X[y == 0, 1], X[y == 0, 2], 'ob')
    ax.plot3D(X[y == 1, 0], X[y== 1, 1], X[y == 1, 2], 'sr')
    ax.plot_surface(x, y, z(x, y))
    ax.view_init(30, 60)
    plt.show()

def plot_2D_surface(model,X,y,h=0.2,**params):
    X0, X1 = X[:, 0], X[:, 1]
    x_min, x_max = X0.min() - 1, X0.max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X1.min() - 1, X1.max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    Z = model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    out = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, **params)
    ax.scatter(X0, X1, c=y, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, s=20, edgecolors='k')
    ax.set_ylabel('y label here')
    ax.set_xlabel('x label here')
    ax.set_xticks(())
    ax.set_yticks(())
    ax.set_title('Decision surface of linear SVC ')
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
```

```
X, y= make_classification(n_samples=4000,n_features=3,n_informative=3,n_redundant=0,random_state=1)
print(X[y==0,2])
model = LinearSVC()
model.fit(X, y)
#plot_2D_surface(model ,X, y, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.8)
plot_3D_surface(model,X,y)
```

i  can't guess  reason of this error, even if i  will check individual  lines like this :
`print(X[y==0,2])`
it works and returns the following  result :
`[-2.03765616  0.00669218 -2.93745161 ... -1.31748082  0.55638536 -1.39934604]`

please help me  to find reason of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You redefine `y` in `plot_3D_surface()` prior to trying to graph it in this line:

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(tmp, tmp)
```

So when you attempt to plot it with plot3D you're no longer using the `y` value that was passed as a parameter. I'd change the variable name to something like:

```
model_x, model_y = np.meshgrid(tmp, tmp)
...
ax.plot_surface(model_x, model_y, z(model_x, model_y))
```